# Вызвать метод, если значение атрибута не заполнено

Tags: python

Есть код, вопрос таков: в последней строчке если не будет селф.токен, хочу, чтобы оно вновь загрузило функцию give_token. Как это сделать, или, возможно, я что-то неправильно понимаю? Или оно само будет прокручивать, пока не получит его?

```
class VKdownloads(object):
    def __init__(self, email, password, scope, client_id):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.scope = scope
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.token = None
        self.user_id = None

    def give_token(self):
        if self.token is None or self.user_id is None:
            self.token, self.user_id = vk_auth.auth(
                self.email, self.password, client_id=self.client_id, scope=self.scope)
    def login(self):
        if not self.token:
```

Comment: 1. Можно было бы сказать что-то конкретное, если бы вы не обрезали пол кода на самом интересном месте
2. Скорее всего, по логике, за это должен отвечать не сам класс VKdownloads, а тот, кто как раз таки его вызывает.

Comment: по логике дальше может идти только вызов метода самого класса, но смысл проверять тут токен, если он проверяется в самом методе give_token?..

Answer (score 1):

Объявите token как `@property` и при получении данных проверяйте, пуста ли приватная переменная `_token`. Если да, вызывайте `give_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Замените `if not self.token:` на `self.give_token()` и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

```
def login(self):
    while not self.token:
        self.give_token()
```